# How can I get entityManager in BaseDao in Karaf 4.0.5?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, entitymanager, apache-karaf

I use `karaf 4.0.5` and hibernate `4.2.15` And I want get `EntityManager` in my BaseDao class. 
If I tried get `EntityManager` in my service

```
<bean id="subscriberService" class="domain.payment.impl.subscriber.SubscriberServiceImpl" scope="singleton"
          init-method="init">
        <tx:transaction method="*" />
    </bean>
```

and in class

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="payment")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I get EntityManager normaly.

But if I tried it in another class

```
public class BaseJpaDao<E> implements BaseDao<E>{
    protected Class<?> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="payment")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseJpaDao(Class<?> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public E persist(E e) {
        entityManager.persist(e);
        return e;
    }
```

My `entityManager` is NULL;

I tried

```
<bean id="baseDao" class="domain.payment.impl.base.BaseJpaDao" scope="singleton"
          init-method="init">
        <tx:transaction method="*" />
    </bean>
```

But it not help.

In Spring project it work fine, but in OSGi I have many problems.

really only from the services I can get `entityManager`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the log ? The `BaseJpaDao` does not seems to have a public empty constructor, so there should be an error in karaf.log saying the the `baseDao`bean cannot be created...

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but it would be worth a try to create an empty constructor and see if it would work then.